# recover my Visual Studio from "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache" deletion

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I was having problems with my Visualstudio 2015 community edition as it was unable to compile and run an new default cordovo project. After multiple attempt of uninstall/install and deleting various cache on the machine to fix the cordova tools, it still did not work.

while working on to fix the issue I accidentally deleted all the data under "**C:\ProgramData\Package Cache**" thinking that this is just a cache but little did I realize that this was an important folder and may have been used by other products as well.

Now when I try to install/uninstall VS.Net 2015, it proceeds very quickly but dose not do anything.

I was wondering if there is another way to manually uninstall the VS.net 2015 or recreate the "Package Cache" which I accidentally deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this but according to [one answer to a related question on Superuser](https://superuser.com/a/616448/348265) by Jonathan Baldwin you can restore Package Cache directory by reinstalling Visual Studio:

> 2. You can delete the files, and if you want to uninstall VS 2012, you can re-run the original installer to put the files back, then uninstall.

In general reinstalling something over a broken install will often allow you to uninstall it. Make sure you select the same set of optional components as you did when you last installed it.

Comment: Thanks, I did try it didn't work as there is no way to force reinstall of all package, but I found a way around that by using /uninstall /force as a additional command line which almost did the trick, but now the VS.Net hangs whenever I open a project that has Cordovo. I was told to try some workaround as mentioned in the ""Windows 10 SDK and Tools" issue which I am unable to find a fix yet. BTW I tried the workaround mentioned here: http://bit.ly/1VWtrQC

Comment: I ran into the same problem and now I am unable to uninstall visual studio neither m I able to install a new one. Did you find a workaround for it? Program Cache has been deleted inorder to install windows 10 SDK.